# Why groups do not show in C# wpf datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am loading data to C# wpf datagrid and I try to show groups in it.
I am following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
I also found this article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/grouping-in-datagrid-in-wpf/ but I prefer approach explained in Microsoft guide.

Here is my xaml code:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
     <local:MachineTools x:Key="machinetools" />
     <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsMachineTools" Source="{StaticResource machinetools}" IsLiveGroupingRequested="True">
         <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
             <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Kinematic"/>
         </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
     </CollectionViewSource>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

and

```
<DataGrid Name="lvTools" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsMachineTools}}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Kinematic" Binding="{Binding Path=Kinematic}" Header="Kinematic"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="olvColumn1ToolName" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="olvDiameter" Binding="{Binding Path=Diameter}" Header="D"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="olvColumnDMin" Binding="{Binding Path=DiameterMin}" Header="DMin"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="olvDiameterMax" Binding="{Binding Path=DiameterMax}" Header="DMax"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="olvColumn6Angle" Binding="{Binding Path=Angle}" Header="Angle"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="olvCuttingLength" Binding="{Binding Path=CutLenght}" Header="CutLength"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="olvFreeLength" Binding="{Binding Path=FreeLength}" Header="FreeLength"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="olvColumn11ToolType" Binding="{Binding Path=ToolType}" Header="Type"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="olvX" Header="X" Binding="{Binding Path=OffSetX}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="olvY" Header="Y" Binding="{Binding Path=OffSetY}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="olvZ" Header="Z" Binding="{Binding Path=OffSetZ}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is code in C#:

```
MachineTools _tools = (MachineTools)this.Resources["machinetools"];
LoadMachineTools(ref _tools);
```

and

```
    public class MachineTools : ObservableCollection<Tool3D>
    {
        // Creating the collection in this way enables data binding from XAML.
    }
```

Tool3D is big class, won't post it here, it implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

I'd like to group on Kinematic column, which is integer

Data is loaded and showing in table, but groups not showing.

For debug purposes I checked `this.lvTools.ItemsSource.Groups` and it had three groups like expected, but - they are not shown in interface.

Why does it happen? How do I show groups?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have sort of solved this question. I used those articles:

- https://rani-irsan.blogspot.com/2022/02/wpf-datagrid-grouping.html
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/grouping-in-datagrid-in-wpf/

I completely removed  `<UserControl.Resources>` section and xaml binding of `DataGrid`. Then, following rani-irsan article I declared binding in code:

```
        public CollectionViewSource _itemSourceList = new CollectionViewSource();
        public ICollectionView Itemlist = null;
        public MachineTools _tools = new MachineTools();
```

and

```
            _itemSourceList.Source = _tools;
            Itemlist = _itemSourceList.View;
            Itemlist.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
            Itemlist.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Kinematic"));
            Itemlist = _itemSourceList.View;
            lvTools.ItemsSource = Itemlist;
```

I also added this style declaration inside my datagrid tag:

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount, StringFormat=Count: {0}}" 
                          Margin="30,0,0,0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

`CanUserAddRows="False"`  could have helped too, maybe but unsure

After that I could get really simple looking group headers in my table. I assume that `DataGrid.GroupStyle` was most helpful